# Text not visible in spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am trying dynamically populate an array with values based on user input. The user has to input a number e.g. 4, and the spinner has to display values (1,2,3,4). So I am using this method:

```
    Integer[] items = new Integer []{0,1};

int size;

   no_of_items_.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    size= (int) Float.parseFloat(no_of_items_.getText().toString());
                    items = new Integer [size];

                    int i=1;
                    for (i=1;i==size;i++)
                    {

                        items[i]=i;


                    }

                    populatespinner();
                }


    public void populatespinner() 
{
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> ItemNumberadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>   (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

    ItemNumberadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    item_no.setAdapter(LayerNumberadapter);



}
```

Now the problem is that when I run the code, the spinner has the same number of items as the user has input, but the rows of the spinner are completely blank. LogCat shows this warning:
        "Text is not set due to it's null"
Any help in this regard will be appreciated, android noob here. :-)

Comment: I think you look into your for loop.

Comment: Could you be more specific @Nil..

Comment: Why you r using like this `Integer[] items = new Integer []{0,1};` u can use `Integer[] items = new Integer [];`

Comment: Saad you said that my answer helped you, so please tagged it as correct answer so that the subject won't stay unanswered !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the loop with i starting by 0 not 1 and see if it helps ?

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
 items[i]=i;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> Options = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

  Options.add(i, i+1);

 }
```